# Blackberry: Simulator stuck up launching through JDE 5.x

Tags: blackberry

When i try to build my project in Blackberry JDE 5.0.0.25. It built successfully. And then when i click on Debug menu "Go" button, simulator is launching and stuck up lanching itself forever, does't come up the simulator screen normally and visible with apps showing.

When i built the same project in Blackberry JDE 4.7, it built successfully and then click on "Go", launched the simulator normally and showed the app to play with it.

Could someone guide me what should be problem? Do i need to set any settings specific to BB JDE 5.x?

I have just the basic hello world empty screen in my project, so don't provide any code here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled and installed again JDE 5.x, which has resolved my issue.

Comment: Next time I suggest you try running clean.bat first, reinstalling is such a pain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what causes the problem, but I've found that opening the windows task manager and killing the BlackBerry device manager task solves the problem for me.